# How do I disable colors in LSP's floating window

Tags: neovim, lsp

The floating window of LSP in neovim uses different colors for different kinds of diagnostics: red for errors, yellow for warnings, etc.

How do I disable all colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlight groups used for LSP diagnostics can be found in `:h diagnostic-highlights`. The main four are the following:

- DiagnosticError
- DiagnosticWarn
- DiagnosticHint
- DiagnosticInfo

The other highlight groups, by default, are linked to these four. So clearing the colors of these (or linking them to `:h hl-Normal`) should be enough. But if you want the colors to be reset only in the floating windows and the colors to remain in the virtual texts, then you'll have to clear the `Floating` variant of the diagnostic-highlights.

```
hi link DiagnosticFloatingError Normal
hi link DiagnosticFloatingWarn Normal
hi link DiagnosticFloatingHint Normal
hi link DiagnosticFloatingInfo Normal
```